# Add SQL function into project with EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-6, sql-function, database-first

I want import my function from SQL Server into my ASP.NET MVC project with EF6 database first.

My problem is when I update database in `.edmx` file, based on what I found in the sources, I open **Model Browser** but in this file I can't use "Add function import" because stored procedure / function name is empty.

What do you think? What is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally I couldn`t find what was the problem, but I got answer by this solution :

I create an **stored procedure** and called my function in it. after that I added stored procedure in my project as easy as possible.

Comment: You can't call a SQL function from EF (or any other data access technology) - you've done the right thing by wrapping it in an SP.